# How to convert array to String using JSON Query

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, json-query

```
{
   "pull_request": {
     "patch_url": null,
   },
   "created_at": "2012-11-14T15:25:33Z",
   "comments": 0,
   "labels": [
     {
       "color": "ededed
     }
   ],
   "id": 8356941,
   "assignees": [
      {
        "login": "Paul",
        "id": 444
      },
      {
        "login": "Steve",
        "id": 222
       }
    ]
```

By JSON Query

`assignees[*].login`, getting below output.

```
["Paul","Steve"]
```

But required as comma separated string without quotes as below,

```
Paul, Steve
```

How to do this in JSON Query?

Comment: assignees[*].login.join(',')

Answer (score 0):

You can use JSON.stringify as below:

JS

```js
const obj = {
  "pull_request": {
    "patch_url": null,
  },
  "created_at": "2012-11-14T15:25:33Z",
  "comments": 0,
  "labels": [{
    "color": "ededed"
  }],
  "id": 8356941,
  "assignees": [{
      "login": "Paul",
      "id": 444
    },
    {
      "login": "Steve",
      "id": 222
    }
  ]
}
const myJSON = JSON.stringify(obj);
console.log(myJSON);
```

If you would like to get comma seperated string for the array it can be done using `join()`

```js
const names = ["Paul","Steve"];
console.log(names.join(", "));
```

Comment: that's not what he asked for.

Comment: This is in Javascript, my use case is to take value from JSON Query alone.
Using below site
jsonquerytool.com, how to get the string values

Answer (score 0):

As long as your title "How to convert array to String" is right, this will work:

```
assignees[*].login.toString()
```